# properties toolbar is empty and does not let load up my forms

Tags: c#

When I open up my project at home the properties bar is completely empty and I can't open up my forms and their coding. I can open up my coding manually by using 'open file' but when I open up the designer it brings up the code for the form and not the form itself. When I open up the project at work it works completely fine and I can open up my forms from the properties toolbar but it doesn't work for me at home.

Comment: To also note I have the same version of c# at home as I do at work

Comment: Sorry but your question is unclear. Are to trying to access code files and designer from Properties pane? if yes, then try opening Solution Explorer from View menu.

Comment: I'm trying to open  the form design from the properties panel but the panel is empty when I open up the project.

Comment: Did you try solution explorer ?

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to view C#? I'm assuming Visual Studio. If so, which version? Do you have any external Form-Tools installed at work but not at home? Something like devexpress?

Generally: Try providing more information, stuff like version numbers, operating systems, used add-ons, etc.

Comment: I 'm using Visual C# 2010 express on windows 8 (it's 7 at work) and I don't have any add-ons installed at home.